# Decorate static methods from class to log ORM access

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, orm, decorator

So I've got the following problem. I am building a flask app with a mongoDB database as backend. Now I want to log all changes to any models in my data storage. Therefore I've started developing some annotations for my database model classes. However, I am struggling with properly decorating the static methods of `mongoengine.Document`.

I've got an `Entry` class which looks like this:

```
from somewhere import db
from Logger import EntitiesLogger

@EntitiesLogger
class Entry(db.Document):
   text = db.StringField()
   resource = db.ReferenceField(Resource)
   meta = {'allow_inheritance': True)
```

My decorator class looks like this (I've added some prints for debugging purposes):

```
def EntitiesLogger(Cls):
    class NewCls(object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.oInstance = Cls(*args, **kwargs)
        def __getattribute__(self, attr):
            try:
                x = super(NewCls, self).__getattribute__(attr)
            except AttributeError:
                print('ERROR')
            else:
                return x
            x = self.oInstance.__getattribute__(attr)
            if type(x) == type(self.__init__):
                print('Data changed')
                return x
            else:
                return x
        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
            print('static method called')

    return NewCls
```

I can now pretty easily call `entry = Entry(...)` and the decorator works. When I access functions of the `db.document` class like `entry.save()` this also works. I only have a problem when I access descriptors of the `db.document` or more specifically my `Entry` class like `Entry.objects(field='something')`. Somehow I need to forward the calls to the static methods like `.objects(...)` to the decorated class, but even with implementing `__get__(...)` this never works. I always receive `AttributeError: type object 'NewCls' has no attribute 'objects'`. Does anybody have an idea how to properly implement this decorator to forward all calls to the decorated class?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You would have to use a metaclass to intercept class attribute lookup, but why not just alter the class in your decorator rather than making a proxy?